# Enable/disable multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, php

Code:

```
<?php
include('conect.php');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `op` WHERE `type` = 2 ;");

   echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'id='datatables-example'>

      <tr>        
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Title 1</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Title 2</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Check 1</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>Title 3</b></td>
          <td class='pure-table'><b>VCheck 2</b></td>              
     </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {

        echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>
        <tr>
        <td>' . $row['Op'] . '</td>
        <td>  <input type='text' name='T2' class='form-control'>
        <td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='C1' id='C1' >
        <td>  <input type='text' name='T3' id='T3' class='form-control' disabled >
        <td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='C2'>
        </tr>
        </tbody>   
       }
        </table>";
        mysqli_close($conn);   
?>

<script language ="JavaScript">                                                      
document.getElementById('C1').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('T3').disabled = !this.checked;
};
</script>
```

I want to enable/disable multiple textboxes generated by the row number of input data.

The first row works fine but the other lines not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I want Enable/disable multiple textbox generated by row number of input data.*, clearly explain your problem. What exactly you're trying to do here?

Comment: `</tbody>   
       }` missed the closing quote. Syntax error. Your `name`s and `id`s are not unique, and you probably want the `tbody` outside the loop as well. There also is no `js` in this question.

Comment: I want list all the values ​​of Op variable and assign values ​​to the textbox T2 and T3 but the second textbox(T3) just want you to be enable when I checked the C1

Comment: @chris85 sorry, edited.

Comment: Your code is still invalid. `VerificacaoAntiga` isn't present in this code.

Comment: It was stress error

Comment: This code would never execute because you never close the `while`. Edit the question to show your **actual** code.

Comment: @chris85 the `while` is close  under `</tbody>`

Comment: No, it isn't. See the comment 19 hours ago, `</tbody> } missed the closing quote`.

Answer (score 0):

None of your `<td>` tags are closed in the second row.

Comment: i fix that and is not the solve of my problem but thanks anyway

Comment: You are calling `onchange` event on a text input. `change` only applies to `select` elements. Use `keyup`, `keydown`, `blur` or `focus` on text input as appropriate for your application. Maybe along those lines, you have `type` set to `C1` and `C2` respectively. Maybe you mean checkbox or radio instead?

Comment: `The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user.`-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: Thanks for the correction on `change`. Never realized that.